# Why some graphs are not displayed?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

When I try to display certain graphs, e. g. **AntilogGraph, IoninKharaghaniGraph, IsobutaneGraph, JankoKharaghaniTonchevGraph**, I get the message **GraphData::notdef: GraphData has no value associated with the specified argument(s)**. Is this problem due to a bug or does it only happen to me with these specific graphs?
My version of Mathematica is 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021) and the version of the GraphData paclet is 12.0.48. I asked this question earlier in the Wolfram Community, but it was deleted, but I don't know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards
[image]

Comment: Works in MMA 13.2 on Windows 10. Note that you need an Internet connection.

Comment: It seems that you don't have the latest version of GraphData paclet. I can confirm that IsobutaneGraph is not available in version 12.3. I can't tell what went wrong in your case. What you might try is to uninstall GraphData Paclets with ``PacletUninstall /@ PacletFind["GraphData_*"]``, then try ``GraphData["IsobutaneGraph"]`` again (with an internet connection available, of course).